# How do you switch between Alm and Celica's story in Fire Emblem Gaiden?

Tags: fire-emblem-gaiden

I've been playing the original Fire Emblem Gaiden on an emulator for a while, and after clearing Zofia Castle, i talked to an NPC and was taken to Celica's story. I've finished the first few levels, but I'm wondering if it's possible to switch between Alm's and Celica's stories at will, as in an option in the menu, or do i always need to talk to an NPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll need to play through quite a bit of story before you have that option without the NPC...it happens once they meet and decide to take different paths.

Comment: when do they meet? i'm guessing Zofia Castle but i could be wrong...

Comment: Yep, you can start switching between the parties at the beginning of Chapter 3 after Celica reaches Zofia's Castle

Comment: does Alm need to be at Zofia Castle when Celica arrives? because i haven't checked, but i think you can go past Zofia Castle in chapter 1?

Comment: I don't believe so. You save at the end at Zofia Castle and Chapter 2 begins right away with Celica and ends as well at Zofia Castle. I might be mixing that up with the remake though.

Comment: so i should be able to switch between parties at will once Celica Reaches Zofia Castle, right?

Comment: Yep, and you'll be able to send items between the parties as well. So, you can switch after every battle or every few battles depending on if you want to pass along certain items or whatever.