# How to transfer party members and items between Alm and Celica's parties in Fire Emblem Gaiden

Tags: fire-emblem-gaiden

i'm completing chapter 3 and have currently conquered all enemies for Alm's party, and have completed up to the mountain village (but just recently got the Holy Sword) with Celica's. I was told in [a previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343737/how-do-you-switch-between-alm-and-celicas-story-in-fire-emblem-gaiden) that I would be able to transfer items and members between the two parties.

So far I haven't figured out how to do that. I tried putting the item in convoy, then having the other party take it out, but it doesn't work, and it doesn't answer how to transfer between party members. [there is a girl in the Forest village whom i think is related to this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344874/what-is-the-function-of-a-certain-npc-in-the-forest-village-in-fire-emblem-gaide), who i believe does some kind of Item Swap(?) but i'm not sure. I was told [in response](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/343737/how-do-you-switch-between-alm-and-celicas-story-in-fire-emblem-gaiden#comment484615_343943) to the previous question

> Yep, and you'll be able to send items between the parties as well. So, you can switch after every battle or every few battles depending on if you want to pass along certain items or whatever.

But when and how does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out, you can transfer items freely if you use easy mode, and as far as i know, there is no way to transfer party members.

Comment: if someone knows how to transfer party members aside from killing them then using the revival heads to get then on the other person's party, please correct me.

Comment: PS, not sure if that even works.