# What is the function of a certain NPC in the Forest Village in Fire Emblem Gaiden?

Tags: fire-emblem-gaiden

I'm done with Alm's set of enemies in chapter 3, and upon entering the Forest Village, there were the usual NPCs, and then there was one who had text I couldn't read (emulator translation issues :p) I soon found out that she was asking for an item, so I gave her a [Leather Shield](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/Leather_Shield). She left immediately after, and I didn't see her in the village again, even after leaving and coming back, and the [Wiki](https://fireemblem.fandom.com/wiki/Forest_Village) didn't say anything about her either. did this have to do with [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/344644/how-to-transfer-party-members-and-items-between-alm-and-celicas-parties-in-fire) in the way that I could transfer items between parties? And if so, is there another NPC who will transfer party members later on?

PS: I went to the village on Celica's route, and i saw the girl again.she asked me for an item (i think), and i gave her another Leather Shield. however, i still have one on the same character. is this the answer to how to transfer items? if so, how do you transfer party members?

Comment: BTW, this will be updated every now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently, that NPC was a person who would trade items between Alm and Celica's parties, but he/she would only do it so many times. that was your only way to trade items in normal mode, and there is another sometime after chapter 3.