# How to unlock Gaiden's Easy mode

Tags: fire-emblem-gaiden

I've been watching an abridged version of Fire Emblem Gaiden, and the Youtuber says he's using Easy Mode. he never mentioned how. how do I get it, and what does it do, exactly? i don't see it on the save select screen when starting a new game, all I get is the beginning of the game.

P.S. I am using an emulator.

Comment: Since you are an emulator, not sure if it's the same, but [Serene Forest](https://serenesforest.net/gaiden/other/hints-and-secrets/) says to "press A while holding Start and Select". Try doing the same combo with your mapped keys

Comment: OK, i'll try that.

Comment: @Wondercricket could you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Serenes Forest](https://serenesforest.net/gaiden/other/hints-and-secrets/), easy mode can be enable by doing the following button combo on the file select screen.

> press A while holding Start and Select. You should be able to choose between NORMAL (Normal Mode) or EASY (Easy Mode).

Since you are playing on an emulator, you should be able to achieve the same by doing the combo with your mapped keys.

As far as the differences go, easy mode awards double experience and you can transfer items between Alm’s and Celica’s parties freely (which can inadvertently answer your [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/344644/124566))